# How to run pree2e script in package.json script for webdriver-manager in AngularCLI

Tags: npm, angular-cli, package.json

I have created default AngularCLI project. The Package.json has following scripts.

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --port=4200",
    "build": "webpack",
    "test": "karma start ./karma.conf.js",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "protractor ./protractor.conf.js",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false --quiet"
```

How do I run pree2e script. I tried both `npm pree2e` and `ng pree2e` but they both didnt work. `webdriver-manager` is used by protractor, it is installed in `C:\...\dw-ng2-app>.\node_modules\protractor\bin\webdriver-manager`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

npm run 'scriptname'. So In my case `npm run pree2e`